# AngularJS check if checkbox is unchecked

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I am trying to show/hide and adjust the ng-required status if a checkbox is checked, but it doesn't seem to managing the variables properly. Here my examples:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxdmodel.value" ng-true-value="'YES'" ng-false-value="'NO'">
```

Input that I want required unless the checkbox is checked in which case it should be hidden and not required:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-hide="checked.YES">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="inputamount">
                    <font color="red">*</font>Expense Amount</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputamount" data-ng-model="itemamount" step="any" ng-required="checked.NO"/>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Is it `checkboxdmodel`? No typo? And in the `ng-hide` isn't it `checkboxdmodel.checked.YES`?

Comment: Please provide js code also which relates 'v' and 'checked.NO'.

Comment: Couldn't you just check for a 'truthy' value on `checkboxmodel.value` by changing your `ng-hide` to `ng-hide="checkboxmodel.value"`. If the box is checked this value will be 'true' and the div will be hidden, otherwise it will be shown.

Comment: I corrected the typo and am using checkbox.value but it is not changing the required behavior for "turning required off" when unchecked. It is working for the ng-show/ng-hide and ng-required that are true when checked. How do I set it to false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/F4hdqWwhIWiqvsJl5ETx?p=preview

No need for the `ng-true` and `ng-false`.

Because checked and unchecked states of the checkbox evaluate to truthy or untruthy, you can just drop the checkbox ng-model value right into wherever you want.  In the case of the ng-required, just invert the value with !.

Comment: That did it. Sometimes that answers are more straightforward!